# Перемещение объектов

Tags: mysql

Здравствуйте! Возник вопрос: есть карта (63 сектора) хранится в BLOB (сериализованный массив), как лучше реализовать перемещение по ней объекта? Допустим есть объект, описанный в другой базе (ID 1 например) и он должен проходить по 1 сектору раз в минуту. Где лучше хранить его местоположение (в базе с объектами или непосредственно на карте) и как изменять?

Дополнительно: необходимо реализовать такую же карту как выше, только на несколько десятков тысяч секторов + таких карт будет очень много. Насколько рационально хранить такое в BLOB?

Comment: @Indev Мое мнение - храните в `BLOB,` и если в какой-то момент вы упретесь в производительность этого подхода, то тогда уже можно начинать думать. Правда, думаю, сейчас набегут сторонники `premature optimization` и насоветуют вам :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вариант с хранением карты в блобе устраивает, то где хранить позицию объекта не так уж и важно. В любом случае целостность данных лежит на плечах софта, а не базы или баз.

Если карты будут большие, то десериализовать, вносить изменения в структуру, сериализовать, записывать в базу может быть накладно. Поэтому хранить в базе с объектами представляется более разумным, тогда карту можно закэшировать и не дергать базу карт на каждое движение.

Comment: А если в BLOB хранится массив типа: 1 => 0, 2 => 0 ... и так до 90000, ничего страшного?

Comment: @Indev Какое хранение в блобе вам удобнее, то и используйте. Если с таким массивом проще работать, значит проще. Есть еще вариант карту битмапами хранить, работать с бинарными данными, а не с массивом, тогда можно сократить объем. В скорости выигрыша скорее всего не будет, если карта статическая - один раз взял из базы и работаешь с ней из кэша, т.е. метод хранения не принципиален...

Comment: Но она не статическая, как в таком массиве на 90к элементов вносить изменения? Заново сериализовать и заносить в базу?

Comment: Склад Эшера? ;) Не знаю какие у вас изменения на карте возможны, по частоте и объему. Сами карты обычно статичны, для хранения изменений можно завести "маску", которая меньше по объему, потом маску накладывать на карту.

Если провести аналогию с граф. редакторами, то есть слой с картой (самый нижний), есть слой с маской (горы превращаются в холмы), есть слой с объектами (объекты перемещаются). если их сложить получится итоговая карта с объектами. При каждом изменении необходимости записывать всю карту нет, а только тот слой, который изменился.

В общем все это теория, вашу задачу не знаю.

Comment: Спасибо большое! А что такое Склад Эшера?)

Comment: > А что такое Склад Эшера?)

Это из хранилища 13. Там был постоянно меняющийся лабиринт, лестницы летали, пол становился стенами, один агент туда вошел и больше его никогда не видели, заблудился.

Comment: Интересно)

Answer (score 1):

Самым правильным вариантом будет хранение карты отдельно, хранение координат объектов отдельно
Отрисовка будет очень простой.